# Capping a cumulative sum by rank

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm new to PowerPivot/DAX and I'm having some trouble with a specific issue I'm trying to resolve. I have a series of products across multiple stores and need to ship a certain amount from as few stores as possible.

A table `Products` contains a list of products and the needed amounts:

```
Product | Need
0000001 |    7
0000002 |    8
```

Another table `Stores` contains the units available by store and I need to calculate how many to send from each store:

```
Product | Store | Units | Send
0000001 | 00001 |     5 |    5
0000001 | 00002 |     2 |    2
0000001 | 00003 |     1 |    0
0000002 | 00001 |     0 |    0
0000002 | 00002 |     3 |    1
0000002 | 00003 |     3 |    3
0000002 | 00004 |     4 |    4
0000002 | 00005 |     2 |    0
```

I have thought of adding a couple of columns for the calculation:

```
Product | Store | Units |  Rank |  CSum |  Send
0000001 | 00001 |     5 |     1 |     5 |     5
0000001 | 00002 |     2 |     2 |     7 |     2
0000001 | 00003 |     1 |     3 |     8 |     0
0000002 | 00001 |     0 |     5 |    12 |     0
0000002 | 00002 |     3 |     3 |    10 |     1
0000002 | 00003 |     3 |     2 |     7 |     3
0000002 | 00004 |     4 |     1 |     4 |     4
0000002 | 00005 |     2 |     4 |    12 |     0
```

First, I rank the stores within each product by units available, solving ties at random:

```
Rank := IF(Units>0,RANKX(ALL(Stores,Stores[Product]),Stores[Units]+RAND())
```

Then, I calculate the cumulative sum:

```
CSum := CALCULATE(SUM(Stores[Units]),
    FILTER(ALL(Stores,Stores[Product]),Stores[Rank]<=MAX(Stores[Rank])))
```

Finally, I calculate the amount to send out:

```
Send := IF(Stores[CSum]>RELATED(Products[Need])+Stores[Units],
    IF(Stores[CSum]<RELATED(Products[Need]),
        Stores[Units],Stores[Units]-(Stores[CSum]-RELATED(Products[Need]))),0)
```

Needless to say, I'm getting `#ERROR`. I think the thought process works, but the formulas are wrong. Also, my `Stores` table has ~2M records with ~20k products, will I have any problem running this?

Comment: If you need to ship from as few stores as possible you will also need to consider the number of stores involved. Consider this: 
 Product | Store | Units | Send
0000001 | 00001 |     5 |    5
0000001 | 00002 |     2 |    2
0000001 | 00003 |     1 |    0
0000002 | 00001 |     0 |    0
0000002 | 00002 |     3 |    3
0000002 | 00003 |     3 |    0
0000002 | 00004 |     5 |    5
0000002 | 00005 |     5 |    0 
You should choose Product 2 from Store 2 instead of Store 3 & Store 5. Time spent computing the result will result in more shipping efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of another solution -- Using VBA-code. First I want to give the whole code and then describe some problems:

```
Const maxStores = 16
Public i As Long
Public j As Integer
Public n As Integer
Public m As Long
Public rangeNeeds As Range
Public rangeHave As Range
Public rangeCost As Range
Sub transportation()

Dim Time1, Time2

Dim Txt As String
Txt = "Enter range with "
Set rangeNeeds = Application.InputBox(prompt:=Txt & "Needs", Type:=8)
Set rangeHave = Application.InputBox(prompt:=Txt & "Inventory", Type:=8)
Set rangeCost = Application.InputBox(prompt:=Txt & "Costs", Type:=8)

' find number of Stores
n = rangeCost.Rows.Count

If n <= maxStores Then
    ' Algorithm #1
    '
    '
    ' Step 1
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' make array of binary numbers & sort it
    Time1 = Timer
    ' make array of indexes
    Dim ArrIndex() As Long
    ReDim ArrIndex(1 To n)
    For j = 1 To n
        ArrIndex(j) = rangeCost(j, 2)
    Next j
    ' make Indexes
    minCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(ArrIndex)
    For j = 1 To n
        If minCost = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Can't count Cost = 0"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ArrIndex(j) = ArrIndex(j) / minCost
    Next j
    ' make array with indexes
    ' each index represents
    ' cost of transportanion
    Dim Index As Long
    Dim ll As Integer
    Dim k, Temp
    k = 2 ^ n - 1
    ll = Len(k) + 1
    Dim Arr()
    ReDim Arr(1 To k)
    For i = 1 To k
        ' count total index
        For j = 1 To n
            Index = Index + CInt(Mid(Dec2Bin(i, n), j, 1)) * ArrIndex(j)
        Next j
        Temp = Index * 10 ^ ll + i
        Arr(i) = Temp
        Index = 0
    Next i
    ' sort Array
    Call Countingsort(Arr)
    ' end of Step1
    ' ========================================================================
    '
    '
    ' Step2
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Go throug each value and find the answer
    Dim ProdNo As Long ' number of products in order
    ProdNo = rangeNeeds.Rows.Count
    Dim ArrHave() As Long
    ReDim ArrHave(1 To ProdNo)
    Dim rangeHaveProd As Range
    Dim rangeHaveStor As Range
    Dim rangeHaveQuan As Range
    Set rangeHaveProd = rangeHave.Columns(1)
    Set rangeHaveStor = rangeHave.Columns(2)
    Set rangeHaveQuan = rangeHave.Columns(3)
    For i = 1 To k ' All Binary Numbers
        Temp = CInt(Right(Arr(i), ll - 1))
        Temp = Dec2Bin(Temp, n)
        ' try fulfill the order
        For j = 1 To n ' All Stores, n -- index of Store
            Index = 0
            Index = CInt(Mid(Temp, j, 1))
            If Index = 1 Then 'If Store is On
                For m = 1 To ProdNo ' All Products, m -- index of Product
                    ArrHave(m) = ArrHave(m) + _
                    WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
                    rangeHaveQuan, _
                    rangeHaveProd, rangeNeeds(m, 1), _
                    rangeHaveStor, rangeCost(j, 1))
                Next m
            End If
        Next j
        ' Check if Needs meets
        Dim CheckNeeds As Boolean
        For m = 1 To ProdNo
            If ArrHave(m) < rangeNeeds(m, 2) Then
                CheckNeeds = False
                Exit For
            Else
                CheckNeeds = True
            End If
        Next m
        If CheckNeeds Then
            Debug.Print "Answer is " & Temp
            Exit For
        Else
            ReDim ArrHave(1 To ProdNo)
        End If
    Next i
    ' end of Step2
    ' ========================================================================
    '
    '
    ' Step3
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' make report
    Sheets.Add
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    With Range("A1")
        .Value = "Report"
        .Font.Size = 22
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    Rows("4:4").Font.Bold = True
    With Ws
    ' Stores table
        .Range("G4") = "Store"
        .Range("H4") = "Cost"
        .Range("I4") = "On"
        rangeCost.Copy
        .Range("G5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        For i = 1 To n
        .Range("I" & 4 + i) = Mid(Temp, i, 1)
        Next i
    ' Needs table
        .Range("K4") = "Product"
        .Range("L4") = "Need"
        rangeNeeds.Copy
        .Range("K5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ' Have table
        .Range("A4") = "Product"
        .Range("B4") = "Store"
        .Range("C4") = "Units"
        .Range("D4") = "On"
        .Range("E4") = "Send"
        rangeHave.Copy
        .Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("D5:D" & 4 + rangeHave.Rows.Count).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],C[3]:C[5],3,0)"
        Dim QForm As String
        QForm = "=IF(RC[-1]=0,0,IF(SUMIFS(C[7],C[6],"
        QForm = QForm & "RC[-4])-SUMIFS(R4C5:R[-1]C,R4C1:R[-1]C[-4],"
        QForm = QForm & "RC[-4])-RC[-2]>0,RC[-2],IF(SUMIFS(C[7],C[6],RC[-4])"
        QForm = QForm & "-SUMIFS(R4C5:R[-1]C,R4C1:R[-1]C[-4],RC[-4])-RC[-2]<0,"
        QForm = QForm & "SUMIFS(C[7],C[6],RC[-4])-SUMIFS(R4C5:R[-1]C,"
        QForm = QForm & "R4C1:R[-1]C[-4],RC[-4]),RC[-2])))"
        .Range("E5:E" & 4 + rangeHave.Rows.Count).FormulaR1C1 = QForm
        Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=""Total Cost = ""&INT(SUMIFS(C[7],C[8],1))"
        Range("A2").Font.Italic = True
        .Calculate
        ' convert formulas into values
        .Range("D5:E" & 4 + rangeHave.Rows.Count) = .Range("D5:E" & 4 + rangeHave.Rows.Count).Value
    End With
    ' end of Step3
    ' ========================================================================
    '
    Time2 = Timer
    Debug.Print Format(Time2 - Time1, "00.00") & " sec."
Else
    MsgBox "Number of stores exceeds Maximum. Need another Algorithm"
End If

End Sub
'Decimal To Binary
' =================
' Source: http://groups.google.ca/group/comp.lang.visual.basic/browse_thread/thread/28affecddaca98b4/979c5e918fad7e63
' Author: Randy Birch (MVP Visual Basic)
' NOTE: You can limit the size of the returned
'              answer by specifying the number of bits
Function Dec2Bin(ByVal DecimalIn As Variant, _
              Optional NumberOfBits As Variant) As String
    Dec2Bin = ""
    DecimalIn = Int(CDec(DecimalIn))
    Do While DecimalIn <> 0
        Dec2Bin = Format$(DecimalIn - 2 * Int(DecimalIn / 2)) & Dec2Bin
        DecimalIn = Int(DecimalIn / 2)
    Loop
    If Not IsMissing(NumberOfBits) Then
       If Len(Dec2Bin) > NumberOfBits Then
          Dec2Bin = "Error - Number exceeds specified bit size"
       Else
          Dec2Bin = Right$(String$(NumberOfBits, _
                    "0") & Dec2Bin, NumberOfBits)
       End If
    End If
End Function

Sub Countingsort(list)
    Dim counts()
    Dim i
    Dim j
    Dim next_index
    Dim min, max
    Dim min_value As Variant, max_value As Variant

'   Allocate the counts array. VBA automatically
'   initialises all entries to 0.

    min_value = Minimum(list)
    max_value = Maximum(list)

    min = LBound(list)
    max = UBound(list)

    ReDim counts(min_value To max_value)

    ' Count the values.
    For i = min To max
        counts(list(i)) = counts(list(i)) + 1
    Next i

    ' Write the items back into the list array.
    next_index = min
    For i = min_value To max_value
        For j = 1 To counts(i)
            list(next_index) = i
            next_index = next_index + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Function Minimum(list)
    Dim i As Long
    Minimum = list(LBound(list))
    For i = LBound(list) To UBound(list)
        If list(i) < Minimum Then Minimum = list(i)
    Next i
End Function

Function Maximum(list)
    Dim i As Long
    Maximum = list(LBound(list))
    For i = LBound(list) To UBound(list)
        If list(i) > Maximum Then Maximum = list(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

First of all want to tell that task is very familiar to [Transportation Problem](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/transportation-problem.html). So I think of possible maths formulas which can find minimal Costs for transportation.

### Problem #1. Big data

This solution goes straight through all combinations. It uses binary numbers to decide which store to select. For example, 01101 means try stores 2,3 and 5. This causes much trouble for computer to count each possibility. So I limited number of stores to 16.

Also I tried this code on 1000 products, not 20k. My computer can't solve this with 20k of products. So someone could make my code work faster.
=>

### Problem #2. Costs

The third table is costs of transportation from each store. I added it to model:

```
| Store | Cost  |
| 00001 |     5 |
| 00002 |     2 |
| 00003 |     1 |
| 00004 |     1 |
| 00005 |    10 |
```

So task is to find minimal transportation cost.
=>

### Excel version

I used formula SUMIFS in my code. It will not work in Excel 2003.
=>

### Conclusion

I believe this gives you some ideas and help someone else to develop the Code.